# Python 2.7: Making a tf : idf script with dictionaries

Tags: python, tf-idf

I want to write a script that uses dictionaries to get the tf:idf (ratio?).

The idea is to have the script find all .txt files in a directory and its sub directories by using os.walk:

```
files = []
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(directory):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.txt'):
        files.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
```

it then uses the list to find all the words and how many times they appear:

```
def word_sort(filename3):
    with open(filename3) as f3:
        passage = f3.read()
    stop_words = "THE OF A TO AND IS IN YOU THAT IT THIS YOUR AS AN BUT FOR".split()
    words = re.findall(r'\w+', passage)
    cap_words = [word.upper() for word in words if word.upper() not in stop_words]
    word_sort = Counter(cap_words)
    return word_sort

term_freq_per_file = {}
for file in files:
    term_freq_per_file[file] = (word_sort(file))
```

It ends up with a dictionary like such:

```
 '/home/seb/Learning/ex15_sample.txt': Counter({'LOTS': 2, 'STUFF': 2, 'HAVE': 1,
                                     'I': 1, 'TYPED': 1, 'INTO': 1, 'HERE': 1,
                                      'FILE': 1, 'FUN': 1, 'COOL': 1,'REALLY': 1}),
```

In my mind this gives me the word frequency per file.

How do I go about finding the actual tf?

And how would I find idf?

By tf i mean the Term Frequency, it is how many times a word (term) appears in a document

TF(t) = (Number of times term t appears in a document) / (Total number of terms in the document).

And by idf i mean the Inverse Document Frequency, where Document Frequency is in how many documents the word appears

IDF(t) = log_e(Total number of documents / Number of documents with term t in it).

To clarify, my question is how do I extract those values and put them into a formula, I know they are there but I don't know how to withdraw them and use them further.

---

I have decided to make another dictionary that holds in what files the word has been used, as such:

```
{word : (file1, file2, file3)}
```

by iterating through the first dictionary like this:

```
for file in tfDic:
     word = tfDic[file][Counter]
     for word in tfDic:
        if word not in dfDic.keys():
            dfDic.setdefault(word,[]).append(file)
        if word in dfDic.keys():
            dfDic[word].append(file)
```

the problem is with this line:

```
word = tfDic[file][Counter]
```

I thought it will 'navigate' it to the word, however I have noticed that the words are Keys in the Counter Dictionary that is a value of the tfDic (the file).

My question is, how to I tell it to iterate through the words (keys of the 'Counter' Dictionary)?

Comment: You can make this clearer by explaining what you expect `tf` and `idf` to be, and what they mean to you...

Comment: are they weighted by certain words?

Comment: You already have "Number of times term t appears in a document", "Total number of documents", and "Number of documents with term t in it", by looking at the dict. So is your question "How do I get the total number of terms in a document?"?

Comment: Your definition of tf is wrong: tf is just the frequency of a term in a document. So you already have tf. idf is a matter of counting (a single loop will do this) and applying the formula.

Comment: `tf * idf` is a product.  The `i` in `idf` stands for "inverse" so it can also be expressed as a ratio `tf / df`.

Comment: You appear to be following http://www.tfidf.com/ but did you click through to the Python implementation at http://code.google.com/p/tfidf/source/browse/trunk/tfidf.py as well?

Comment: One of the features of tf-idf is that you should not need to maintain a stop-word list -- the words with a high Document Frequency will be naturally given a high divisor by the algorithm.

Comment: You've not correctly defined the tf and idf. Have a look to this formulation in order to improve your algorithm: http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/term-frequency-and-weighting-1.html

Comment: @tripleee I'm aware of the stop words, it is just a part of code I have used for something else and have yet not cleaned it up :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with your current data structure, you have to delve through the entire structure for each file for each word in order to calculate its `idf`.

```
# assume the term you are looking for is in the variable term
df = 0
for file in files:
    if term in term_freq_per_file[file]:
        df += 1
idf = math.log(len(files)/df)
```

An earlier version of this answer contained a sketch for an alternative data structure, but this is probably good enough.

Comment: I have replaced my answer with a completely different one.  Please refresh.

Comment: You might want to remove the now-obsolete comment, like I have done with mine. (Click the little grey X on the right which is visible when you hover over it.)

Comment: Thank you, how do I know what to put after "if"? I get an error saying name 'term' is not defined. This is one of the things that confuses me. Do I need to change my function so it 'reacts' to "term" or "word"?

Comment: As the comment explains already, the variable should contain the word you want to calculate the tf*idf value for.

Comment: I have updated and edited my question a bit, could you have a look at it please?

Comment: My suggestion would be to roll back your edit (there's a button for that in the [edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25529141/revisions)) and post the new content as a separate, new question instead. Include a link to this question. Consider accepting my answer, or posting one of your own and accepting that so that this question no longer shows up as unresolved.

Comment: I have just solved the problem now, will post it and end this question, thanks a lot for all of your help and time

Answer (score 0):

(finally)

I decided to go back and change my word count formula, so that instead of:

```
word_sort = Counter(cap_words)
```

I have iterated through the words in a list and made my own dictionary with how many times they appear:

```
word_sort = {}
for term in cap_words:
    word_sort[term] = cap_words.count(term)
```

so instead of having a sub dictionary (Counter) every time, I end up with this for tfDic:

```
'/home/seb/Learning/ex17output.txt': {'COOL': 1,
                                   'FILE': 1,
                                   'FUN': 1,
                                   'HAVE': 1,
                                   'HERE': 1,
                                   'I': 1,
                                   'INTO': 1,
                                   'LOTS': 2,
                                   'REALLY': 1,
                                   'STUFF': 2,
                                   'TYPED': 1},
```

and then I iterate through the keys of the tfDic[file] to create another Dictionary that holds the info in what files a given word has been used:

```
for file in tfDic:
word = tfDic[file].keys()
for word in tfDic[file]:
    if word not in dfDic.keys():
        dfDic.setdefault(word,[]).append(file)
    if word in dfDic.keys():
        dfDic[word].append(file)
```

and the final result is as such:

```
 'HERE': ['/home/seb/Learning/ex15_sample.txt',
      '/home/seb/Learning/ex15_sample.txt',
      '/home/seb/Learning/ex17output.txt'],
```

Now I plan on just 'extracting' the values and putting them into the formula I mentioned before.

Comment: A `Counter` is just a subclass of `dict` so it has the same methods.  I agree that having `Counter` in the output is a bit misleading; for your purposes, it really is just a dict, and you should ignore the `Counter` identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Unless this is a learning exercise on how tf-idf works, I'd recommend using the built-in [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/index.html) classes to do this.

First, create an array of the count dictionaries for each file. Then feed in your array of count dictionaries to [DictVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer.html), and then feed the output sparse matrix to [TfidfTransformer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfTransformer.html)

`from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
dv = DictVectorizer()
D = [{'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}, {'foo': 3, 'baz': 1}]
X = dv.fit_transform(D)
tv = TfidfTransformer()
tfidf = tv.fit_transform(X)
print(tfidf.to_array())`